# What are "ferry terminal" and "car ferry"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I have encountered many *ferries* in that small abstract of text, but don't quite get what it is. Could u explain, please?

> However, once you get to the end of the road and **the ferry terminal**,
>   you look across the sea and see a huge mountainous, almost forbidding,
>   island rising up in front of you. I felt a frisson of excitement, or
>   was I just a bit nervous, as I had also just seen **a rusting car ferry**
>   approaching the small pier?
>
> We crossed without mishap, but left **the ferry** stuck behind a convoy of
>   trucks carrying construction materials ready to concrete over this
>   beautiful island. From the ferry stop, the road rises abruptly over a
>   small hill and then as it comes down the other side we enter tourist
>   land.

Comment: Please don't use "u" here for "you", as it could confuse learners who are not yet at your level.

Comment: @TRomano I was confused the first time I saw it in the mail from international friend of mine. Still it's a good chance to learn about modern shortenings as it is everywhere around on the Web. But I respect your opinion and will use the complete form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **[Ferry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferry)**
   A ship (or ship-like thingy) to transport people or vehicles acros a stretch of water. Sometimes across a river, sometimes across the sea to an island.
2. **Car ferry**
   A ferry to transport cars (as opposed to a ferry for pedestrians or even railroad waggons). Like this:
   [image: car ferry]
3. Ferry terminal
   A terminal literally is a place where a line (->bus, railroad, ferry) ends, but in fact just a place where it stops and passengers go on board or leave. Ferry terminal: a terminal on a ferry line.

Other ferries are not mentioned in your text:

- The "rusting car ferry" is basically an old and rusty car ferry and
- the last example was connected wrong, it should make sense if read like this:

  > We crossed without mishap, but (left the ferry) (stuck behind a convoy of trucks).

Comment: Got it finally! So many tnx.

Comment: When they drove off of the ferry, they found themselves "stuck behind"  (impeded by) many trucks.  Large trucks are usually directed to the main deck center lane on a ferry—they are too big for side lanes or upper ramps. So when the ferry arrives at port, the trucks get to drive off first, and cars after. Many islands have hilly two-lane roads, so it's hard to pass those trucks.  http://www.google.com/search?q=washington+ferries&client=safari&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=2UMJVe_WC4nzoASywYG4Ag&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=washington+ferries

Comment: I believe RORO sea ferries qualify as car ferries too, and they are very big ships. Their terminals more resemble airport terminals...